# Colocar varios valores en nusoap

Tags: php, sql, webservice

Tengo los valores

```
$peso_1
$alto_1
$ancho_1
$largo_1
```

y tengo un web service, llamado Tarificador, dentro de este hay un parametro llamado **"XmlEnviosDetalle"** el cual debe de enviar el siguiente valor:

```
{$peso_1_$alto_1_$ancho_1_$largo_1}
```

En otras palabras, los valores que se envian seria asi:

```
{1_2_3_4}
```

**Mi codigo `PHP` es el siguiente:**

```
    <?php
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            require_once('../../lib/nusoap.php');

            $url = 'localhost:8080/WebServices/GestionAlbaranes.asmx?wsdl';
            $soapclient = new nusoap_client($url, TRUE,array('encoding' =>'UTF-8',));
            $function = 'AATarificador';
            $params = array('strXmlEnviosDetalle'=>,); //Aqui es mi problema
            $result = $soapclient->call($function , $params);

            if (!$error = $soapclient->getError())
            echo "Resultado: ".print_r ($result);
            else
            echo "ERROR:".print_r ($error);
    ?>
```

Mi pregunta sería, ¿como puedo enviar los valores mencionados a traves de nusoap?

Answer (score 0):

Para los que recien estan entrando en este mundo de NuSoap, les dejo esta solución.

Si tienes valores $a , $b , $c y necesitas colocarlo en un parametro "X" que encierre a todos ellos, simplemente forma una variable que encierre a las demás.

$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = 3;

$z = '{' . $a . '*' . $b . '*' . $c . '}';

y asi puedes ponerlo como parametro dentro de tu soap.